# Tensorflow Shuffling Data Twice During Preprocessing

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

In the TensorFlow Load Images [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images), the authors seem to shuffle the data twice when working with tf.data:

```
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data_dir/'*/*'), shuffle=False)
list_ds = list_ds.shuffle(image_count, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)  # <-- first shuffling

val_size = int(image_count * 0.2)
train_ds = list_ds.skip(val_size)
val_ds = list_ds.take(val_size)
...

def configure_for_performance(ds):
    ds = ds.cache()
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)  # <-- second shuffling
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    return ds

train_ds = configure_for_performance(train_ds)
val_ds = configure_for_performance(val_ds)
```

My question is whether that second shuffling is necessary or yields any other advantages that I am not aware of? Additionally, why is the buffer_size set fixed to 1000 instead of using AUTOTUNE there as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They shuffle twice for different reasons:

1. The first shuffle is to get a shuffled and consistent trough epochs train/validation split.
2. The second shuffle is to shuffle the train dataset at each epoch.

Explaination:

1. The `shuffle` method has a specific parameter `reshuffle_each_iteration`, that defaults to`True`. It means that whenever the dataset is exhausted, the whole dataset is reshuffled. If one is splitting one dataset into two after a call to `shuffle`, (to get an randomized split), when the dataset will be exhausted, the whole dataset will be reshuffled before the split. The train set and validation set then are mixed together.  So, to get an randomized split, but consistent between epochs, shuffle with `reshuffle_each_iteration=False`
2. Then, for the training set, it's better to feed the model with data in a different order at each epoch, hence the call to shuffle a second time.

---

For your 2nd question, `tf.data.AUTOTUNE` is simply not compatible with `shuffle`.

Comment: thanks for the insight. Do you happen to know anything about my second question as well?

Comment: I did not answer that question because it's bad pratcice to ask multiple questions in one on stackoverflow. But the answer is simply that `shuffle` is not compatible with `tf.data.AUTOTUNE`.